# Problem with method_exists() Or loaded _before_ unserialize() Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, queue

method_exists(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that my file was named SendEmailJob and my php class sendEmailJob, so I had uppercase file and my lowercase class